# How to group by one column and return ifnull for the other column

Tags: sql, vertica

Example Data:

```
event_id, session_id, did_tap_on_screen
1         1           true
2         1           false
3         2           false
4         2           false
```

Desired Results:

```
session_id, did_tap_on_screen
1           true
2           false
```

Basically, I want to group by the session_id and return true for did_tap_on_screen if any is true and return false if all are false

This is the pseudo query I wrote:

```
SELECT
  session_id,
  did_tap_on_screen -- what should I do here
FROM events
GROUP BY session_id
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  And what data type is the second column?

Answer (score 1):

If `did_tap_on_screen` is a string, you could do:

```
select session_id, max(did_tap_on_screen)
from events
group by session_id;
```

If it is a boolean (of some type), then the appropriate formulation depends on the database.  For instance, Postgres supports `bool_or()`

```
select session_id, bool_or(did_tap_on_screen)
from events
group by session_id;
```

Comment: Hey The database that I am using is vertica. What keywords should I use to find the appriopriate function to use? The data type is boolean.

Comment: @samol. First solution here above works. You just have to cast `did_tap_on_screen` to integer: `...max(did_tap_on_screen::integer)`. This will return 0/1 instead of false/true. If you want false/true in output cast max() result back to boolean: `...max(did_tap_on_screen::integer)::boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to determine whether at least one `did_tap_on_screen` per `session_id` is true:

```
select session_id,
    count(case when did_tap_on_screen then 1 end) > 0
from events
group by session_id
```